# Array Conditional Filtering (ArrayFire)

Tags: arrayfire

I have two arrays A (2D image) and B (1d intensity values) and trying to make third one (2D) with will be size of A but contain only values of A that B has. What will be the the right way to do that without moving data to the host?
PS: Trying to find a way to work with result of function 'regions' (mask out certain regions and keep others).
Thanks.